# Thrown exception is not caught properly, causing my app to crash

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have these two functions

```
    override suspend fun getUser(loadUserImage: Boolean): BaseResult<User> =
        withContext(realmWriteDispatcher) {
            getResult {
                RealmDb.useRealm { user()?.mapToUser() }
            }
        }

    private fun Realm.user(): RealmUser {
        findFirst<RealmUser>()?.let { return it }

        sessionRepository.logout()
        loginNavigation.onLoggedOut()

        throw UserNotFoundException()
    }
```

Basically anywhere in the app, you can fetch the current user from realm, and if it does not exist, it means the user is logged out and this call somehow happened by mistake. It will force the user back to the home screen if it has not already happened.

It will throw a UserNotFound() exception which extends `Exception`.

`getResult` looks like this

```
suspend fun <T : Any> getResult(sourceCall: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T?) = coroutineScope {
    runCatching {
        BaseResult.Ok(sourceCall())
    }.getOrElse {
        when (it) {
            is Exception -> BaseResult.Error(exception = it)
            else -> BaseResult.Error(exception = Exception("failed to get result"))
        }
    }
}
```

Where runCatching is part of kotlin, and should act like a try catch.

The problem is that I am seeing users in the field hitting these crashes. The getUser call happens a lot throughout the app, so it is difficult to track down. Does anyone know how this can happen?

It is the place where it crashes, and is the central way for the app to fetch the user.

Comment: I can offer a guess: [coroutine cancellation is handled with a specific exception](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative), `CancellationException`. `runCatching { }` [can break coroutine cancellation](https://twitter.com/Zhuinden/status/1389063911702470656). Try replacing `runCatching { }` with a try/catch with a specific exception, or re-throw `CancellationException`.

Comment: So you mean you observe something like uncaught exception `UserNotFoundException`? Are you sure it could be thrown from the above code only?